# Sliding Puzzle w/ multiple solutions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, combinatorics

I am trying to write an algorithm which produces a solution to a modified n by n sliding puzzle (assuming that an end state is reachable from the given start state). The change is as follows: tiles can belong to sets with other tiles and can occupy any of their positions as well, and the sets are disjoint. The image below shows an example on the right which is in one of many end states. A tile labeled with x numbers could be in any of the x positions it is labeled with. For example:

on the left we have 3x3 of: $\left\lbrace1\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace2\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace3\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace4\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace5\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace6\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace7\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace8\right\rbrace,$ and
on the right we have a 3x3 $\left\lbrace1,4,6\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace2,8\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace3\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace5\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace7\right\rbrace.$

My current thinking is to treat each tile as being in its own set, and exhaustively check if the initial state is solvable - in this example labeling the tiles in positions $1 $ (top left)$, 2, 4, 6,$ and $8$  as respectively $\left\lbrace1\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace2\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace4\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace6\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace8\right\rbrace$, then $\left\lbrace4\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace2\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace6\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace1\right\rbrace, \left\lbrace8\right\rbrace$, etc. and running some existing algorithm for the original puzzle if a solvable state is found.

[image: Original Puzzle vs Modified]

Comment: It would be better to articulate the specific question you want answered.  I understand you'd like an algorithm, but do you have any requirements on it?  Running time?  Size of puzzle it must handle?  I don't the restrictions on solutions.  Do the restrictions on where a tile can appear apply only to the start and end state, or does each intermediate position (obtained by sliding a single tile) also have to satisfy the requirement?  What research have you done?  Have you looked into algorithms for the sliding tile problem without this constraint?  What have you found so far?

Comment: This modified version of the sliding-tile puzzle resembles a lot the way Pattern Databases are computed for this domain. Two comments: first, there is no need to check if an instance is solvable using a brute force search, observing the parity of the permutation suffices; secondly, as said, build a Pattern Database and use it to solve the problem. It will actually produce optimal solutions

Comment: I would like it to be polynomial time and able to handle large puzzles, say on the order of 100x100. I am confused about what you mean by the intermediate positions, but if you are asking if tiles can be on positions that they are not labeled with when it is not at an end state, yes they can. I have only read briefly about sliding puzzles and now I have read 2 papers about pattern databases and it seems like a promising way forward.

Comment: Carlos, could you elaborate on how to check the parity of the permutation?